# How to throw an exception when no value is returned in a function?

Tags: function, c++11, hash, return-value

I am making a custom hash table based on linear probing, in C++11, in which I have made a `get()` function. The function should return a value corresponding to the key in the hash table. This is my code:

```
template<class Key, class Value>    
Value OpenMap<Key,Value>::get(const Key& k){
    int index = hash(k);
    int i = index;
    do{
        if(buff[i].empty)
            break;
        if(buff[i].elem.key==k)
            return buff[i].elem.value;
        i = (i+1)%capacity;
    }while(i!=index);
}
```

The problem is, every key passed may not have a corresponding value in the hash table. In this function, I am unable to  get how to handle this exception. What can be the possible ways to handle this exception, and how does the C++ STL `unordered_map<>` handle this?

Comment: [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) solves the problem by *creating* an entry in the table. If you use the indexing operator ([`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at)) to get an element from the map, and the key doesn't exist then an entry is created by default-constructing the value. Then the newly constructed value is returned.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah, but that's what the `operator[]` does. In my code, I also have a similar function which adds in case there is no value of the corresponding key. But I need to handle exception in this `get(Key)`  function.

Comment: Okay, I understand. In that case `std::unodered_map` deals with it by not having a direct `get` function at all. Instead it have the [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) function which returns an iterator. So it simply side-steps your problem by avoiding it.

Comment: @Joachim std::unordered_map::at.

Answer (score 0):

You could `throw` an exception when no value is found, then in your code, you surround `get(...)` with `try-catch` statement

```
class MyException{
    // ordinary class
}

template<class Key, class Value>    
Value OpenMap<Key,Value>::get(const Key& k){
     int index = hash(k);
     int i = index;
     do{
         if(buff[i].empty)
             break;
         if(buff[i].elem.key==k)
             return buff[i].elem.value;
         i = (i+1)%capacity;
    }while(i!=index);
    throw MyException();
}

...
OpenMap<int, int> myMap;
try{
    int value = myMap.get( 10 );
}catch( MyException & ex ){
    // do whatever you want witn ex
}
...
```

note that `MyException` is an ordinary class, so it can have constructor and methods, for example you could pass `key` as parameter and then print a messagge that this key wasn't found.

Answer (score 0):

I would throw `std::invalid_argument`, although `std::domain_error` and `std::out_of_range` would also make sense.

The caller would just catch `std::exception`.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider `optional`. It is in C++17 standard [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional). You can use boost::optional for now. An `optional` can be checked for value and `.get()` can be called if it has value. The value can be overridden at any time and can also be accessed like a pointer.

```
template<class Key, class Value>    
boost::optional<Value> OpenMap<Key,Value>::get(const Key& k){
    int index = hash(k);
    int i = index;
    do{
        if(buff[i].empty)
            break;
        if(buff[i].elem.key==k)
            return buff[i].elem.value;
        i = (i+1)%capacity;
    }while(i!=index);
    return boost::none;  // empty optional
}
```